# Firebase Multiple Images

Tags: javascript, firebase, image-uploading, firebase-storage

I'm sort of new at Firebase and I was wondering if anyone knows how to upload multiple images to firebase at once? I am creating a website where I want to have several upload file buttons and use Javascript to have all of those images be uploaded at once to Firebase Storage under the same ID. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "under the same ID"?  Each file has to have a unique path within a Storage bucket.  And there's nothing stopping you from invoking the Storage apis to kick off multiple transfers at the same time.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how I'd upload multiple images at once with a single "submit" button? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

First, look at js [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) for an example snippet of how to allow user to select multiple images (files) for upload.

Then have a look at the [firebase storage upload files documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) for an example of how to upload.

I imagine a `promise.all` / race condition would be the best way to handle multiple images...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
// set it up
firebase.storage().ref().constructor.prototype.putFiles = function(files) { 
  var ref = this;
  return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
    return ref.child(file.name).put(file);
  }));
}

// use it!
firebase.storage().ref().putFiles(files).then(function(metadatas) {
  // Get an array of file metadata
}).catch(function(error) {
  // If any task fails, handle this
});
```